# How to determine the minimum height of a roller coaster provided an acceleration as a threshold parameter?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I've been going in circles (no pun intended) with this problem for several hours and yet I can't seem to find what am I doing wrong or misunderstanding, hence I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

It states as follows:

> A 1500-kg roller coaster (including passengers) passes point A at $3\,\frac{m}{s}$(see figure 1 as a reference). Due to safety concerns, you must design the
>   track so that at point B the passengers do not experience an upward
>   force that exceeds 4g. If the arc at B is circular with radius 15
>   m,(a) determine the minimum value of h that satisfies this
>   requirement,and (b) determine the speed of the coaster at C.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Figure 1. Illustrates the problem as it appears in my book

Part a. In my attempt to solve the problem. I thought that the key was to use the conservation of mechanical energy in both points. In A and B.
As this is described in Figure 2. I also thought that because the Radius of the circle is given then there is an *implicit hint* that the upward acceleration they're talking about is the **centripetal acceleration** (the one which is pulling to the center of the circle, hence upwards), so that this must not exceed 4g. As a consequence I equated both expressions in order to obtain the speed v_b so with that all there is left to solve is the height which is given by the potential energy U reached at that point.

For better visualizing of the situation I made an sketch of all the forces which I could find, seen in Figure 2.

[image: Sketch of the solution]

The above paragraph is summarized in the following equations:

$$E_a=E_b$$

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2_a+mgh_a=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_b+mgh_b$$

Mass cancels in both expressions and multiplied by $2$:

$$v^2_a+2gh_a=v^2_b+2gh_b$$

$$h_b=\frac{v^2_a+2gh_a-v^2_b}{2g}$$

Edit:

Apparently there is an acting force which is going outwards the circle, this summed up with Newton's second law would yield:

$$\frac{mv^2_b}{R}+mg=m\left(a_{max}\right)$$

(Here's where I use the fact of the "threshold of $4g$)

$$\frac{mv^2_b}{R}+mg=m\left(4g\right)$$

$$v^2_b=3gR$$

Inserting this final expression into the one obtained earlier:

$$h_b=\frac{v^2_a+2gh_a-3gR}{2g}$$

Then all is left is to insert the values given and make the computation of the height:

$$h_b=\frac{\left(3\,\frac{m}{s}\right)^2+2\times 9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}\times 40\,m-3\times9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}\times 15\,m}{2\times 9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}}$$

$$h_b=\frac{\left(3\,\frac{m}{s}\right)^2+2\times 9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}\times 40\,m-3\times9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}\times 15\,m}{2\times 9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}}$$

Computing this expression yields:

$h_{b}=17.95918367\,m$

Which results with what my book describes as $h_b\approx 17.96\,m$

Part b. Is very straightforward. It was just comparing both Energies from the top in A and lower in C as stated below.

This process is illustrated in Figure 3.

[image: Sketch of the second solution]

$$E_a=E_c$$

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2_a+mgh_a=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_c+mgh_c$$

Again masses cancels and multiplying by $2$:

$$v^2_a+2gh_a=v^2_c+2gh_c$$

$$v^2_c=v^2_a+2gh_a-2gh_c$$

$$v_c=\sqrt{v^2_a+2gh_a-2gh_c}$$

$$v_c=\sqrt{v^2_a+2g\left(h_a-h_c\right)}$$

Finally inserting the given values into the above equation:

$$v_c=\sqrt{\left(3.0\,\frac{m}{s}\right)^2+2\times 9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}\left(40\,m-20\,m\right)}$$

Which results into:

$$v_c= 20.02498439\,\frac{m}{s}$$

This answer does check with what my book lists as the correct answer, $20.02\,\frac{m}{s}$ rounded to two decimals.

Although the procedure which I intended to do initially seems reasonable, I'm still dumbfounded on why part a doesn't check, so far I believe I haven't overlooked anything, but if I did, please explain me where is the mistake and some conceptual basis as maybe I could have misinterpreted something.

Comment: Are you certain that this is the right site for your problem? Have you tried [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)? It might be off-topic there, though, on account of their stance on homework (and homework-like) problems. I don't know.

Comment: @Arthur I thought that maths was an appropiate site as my question is about if my use of mathematics was right given the conditions of the problem. I am not very experienced in the field so, verification of my reasoning is needed.

Comment: Where did you get $v_a = 3$ m/s from?

Comment: @caverac Sorry it was a typo. It was a given data from the problem, now I've corrected that mistake.

Comment: When you calculate $h_b$ you use $R = 10$ m, is that also a typo?

Comment: @caverac Sorry, this was a mistake from my part. During a rush in the transcription from my writting sheets, but as you pointed out should had been $R=15\,m$.

Answer (score 3):

The downward force felt by a passenger of mass $m$ at point $B$ has two components:

- The weight of the passenger, $mg\downarrow$
- The radial force, $\frac{mv_b^2}R\downarrow$

Your equation gets modified as $mg+\frac{mv_b^2}R=4mg$, solving which gets you $h_b=17.96$m.

[image: Figure1][image: Figure2]

**Edit.** Let us first discuss the answer in ground frame. As you have correctly pointed out, a radially upward acceleration with magnitude $\frac{mv_b^2}R$ is required to maintain circular motion of the roller coaster at point $B$. The required 'centripetal force' is delivered by the normal reaction at point $B$. This is because there is no agent exclusively exerting the centripetal force; the normal reaction and gravitational force are the only forces acting on the coaster.

As seen from the free body diagram of the coaster, $$N-mg=\frac{mv_b^2}R$$ Since the upward force on the coaster is $N$, you require $$N\le4mg\implies\frac{mv_b^2}R+mg\le4mg$$

Now, for the solution in the frame of reference of the roller coaster. Imagine being seated on the coaster. You would perceive yourself to be at rest without acceleration while the world around would be moving circularly. You would also feel more compressed at $B$: this suggests that in your reference frame, a certain phantom force other than your weight acts downward. This force is called the pseudo-force; 'pseudo', because it doesn't actually exist. It is merely an arrangement to solve in accelerated frames of reference.

Recall that the centripetal acceleration has direction opposite to that of its corresponding pseudo-force. In general too, for an object with acceleration $\vec  a$ in ground frame, the pseudo-force acting on the object in its frame of reference is $-m\vec a$; that is, it has magnitude $ma$ and direction opposite to $\vec a$. This gives $$N=mg+\frac{mv_b^2}R$$ since in this frame, the coaster is at rest so the forces cancel. Once again, the upward force is $N$, which gives you the same result as the ground frame.

Comment: Shubham.Yes, mv^2/R = Reaction(upward) -mg.+)

Comment: @Shubham John Why the radial force goes downwards and not upwards?. Can you explain to me this part?. I thought that the radial force goes into the circle not the other way around. Perhaps am I mistaking this?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The centrifugal force is a pseudo-force and has the direction opposite to that of the centripetal acceleration.

Comment: Think about it: at the bottom of the coaster, doesn't one feel compressed?

Comment: @Shubham John I am not familiar with the concept of pseudo-force. Checking with my book it states that "centripetal acceleration" is inward seeking. Yes indeed when you're at the bottom you feel compressed but I don't know to which force is due this. Do you know any link where I can read more about it?

Comment: @Shumbhan John. Could it be that other way to look it as comparing centripetal force and the reaction force due to the weight, now these two are looking "upward" as the problem states, and will render the result. But I'd appreciate you could help me with the concepts. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Your interpretation looks correct too; it applies in ground frame, that is, with respect to a stationary observer on the ground. I have discussed the directions of forces in the non-inertial frame of reference of a passenger seated on the coaster. You can learn more about pseudo-forces (more specifically about centrifugal forces) [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force).

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The force experienced by a passenger is equal to the normal force from the track (there are only two forces acting, and gravity is never something you feel). At $B$, in order to keep the cart on the track, the normal force fights gravity and supplies centripetal acceleration. Thus the centripetal force and gravity add together.

Comment: @Arthur I don't understand the part where you say that at $B$ in order to keep the cart on track the normal force fights the gravity. Can you explain it with details?.Let's say in a flat surface where everything is set, the weight is always pulling down and normal up, in this case a cart for example stays on top and it will not go anywhere, however when there is motion ocurring in a circle, it doesn't seem to be the case. Can you explain this better?.How does the normal "helps" to keep the cart on track? wouldn't be the gravity alone as it pulls the object downwards such like in flat surface?.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Sorry on misspelling your nick. I think that the problem "alluded" to as solving it from a stationary observer. Not sure if this was the case but it seems that the key was to realize the "reactive force". I did looked at the link your provided but the article in wiki is rather extense and not very digestible for someone looking an explanation with some visual aid or in layman terms. Perhaps do you know some reference which does have some examples and pictures of this situation?. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell But the cart _isn't_ just standing still on a flat track. It's accelerating upwards. And the only force available to allow it do that is the normal force. And saying that the normal force "helps" the cart stay on track isn't entirely true. We _know_ that the cart follows the track exactly, and the normal force is exactly as large as it needs to be in order to ensure this. At $B$ we know gravity is acting on the cart, 1g down. We also know that following the track means it's accelerating at 3g upwards. The only unknown term is the normal, and it must be 4g by Newton's 2nd.

Comment: @Arthur Did the arrows I made in my diagrams are correct?. So I can picture the situation better. What I don't understand is *why* the normal force ensures the cart stay on track if the normal force is pointing upwards and not downwards?. It is the concept is where I'm still stuck at. I'm giving the impression that the cart will go flying off anywhere when it reaches point $B$ if it where not because of the reactive force alluded but *how* if it at this instant for me seems contrary to my intuition. Can you help me to understand this better?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I actually meant for you to read the introduction and head over to the circular motion section in the examples. I am on mobile so I couldn't access the internal link for that section on Mobile Wikipedia. I'm going to edit my answer for a bit more explanation on both ground and accelerating frames. I don't think the question preaches any particular way of solving as long as the answer is correct.